# Fortify 4.40 cannot find Java 8 on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, fortify

We have installed Fortify 4.40 on a Linux server, and we have an Ant task that executes the sourceanalyzer.  The sourceanalyzer is able to run, although it runs out of memory on the Linux server, so I installed Fortify on my PC to see if I could get it to work there.

When I try to run the Ant task on my PC, I get the following error:

```
[sourceanalyzer] [error]: Unable to find a suitable Java VM. The following were attempted:
[sourceanalyzer] > C:\Program Files\HP_Fortify\HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.40\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll: File does not exist or is not executable.
[sourceanalyzer] > C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll: There are no more files.
[sourceanalyzer] > jvm.dll: File does not exist or is not executable.
[sourceanalyzer] > java: Verbose parse failed to find a path.
[sourceanalyzer] Please verify the integrity of your HP Fortify installation, or set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to a pre-existing Java installation that meets minimum requirements given in the user guide.
[sourceanalyzer] Result: 1
```

First of all, there is no `jre` subdirectory under my `C:\Program Files\HP_Fortify\HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.40` folder.  I did try copying over the `jre\bin\server` subtree from my `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74` folder, but that only resulted in a `There are no more files` error instead of `File does not exist or is not executable`.

Second of all, there is a `jvm.dll` file in my `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre\bin\server` folder, so I don't know what `There are no more files` means.

Third of all, I did re-run the Fortify installation program, so I don't think there is any integrity issue with my Fortify installation.

Fourth of all, my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74`, which is the correct value for my Java 8 installation.  Fortify 4.40 supports Java 8, as I don't get these errors on the Linux server.

Why can't Fortify find my Java VM on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else runs into this issue like me, Fortify spits out this same error message if you pass in the `-Xmx` flag incorrectly.

I was using `-Xmx10GB` when the correct syntax is `-Xmx10G` (do not put a `B`). Obviously, if you're going to allocate more than 2GB of memory to the process, you will also need the `-64` flag to have the process run in 64-bit mode, along with a 64-bit installation of Java.